# Chronic back pain after deadlift injury

Tags: back-pain

I workout a lot and one day during my deadlift, I exceded my limit. So, I had a little pain a while after that in my lower back and it evolved a little bit. I went to the doctor and checked it. He told me that it is a lower back pain in the tendons right in the lumbar region. He gave me some muscle relaxant and it really helped for that time. After I finished the treatment the pain stayed but not like before. So I started stretch more when working out and focused on the form not on the weight. But it has been 4 months and the pain still there. Some said it may be a chronic lower back pain. Is there some kind of workout that might help to cure it?

Comment: Read into Trigger Point Therapy and Massaging away Scar Tissue. The Trigger Point Therapy Workbook by Claire Davies is an essential read. Often there is a chronic unresolved muscular issue behind these kind of injuries that needs encouragement to begin healing again and restoring to proper function and feeling.

Answer (score 7):

Summit Medical Group has some great rehabilitation resources. [Here](http://www.summitmedicalgroup.com/library/senior_health/low_back_pain_exercises/) are some strengthening and stretching exercises they recommend for people with low back pain.

[image]

On the page linked above, they also suggest sports and activities to avoid, as well as activities that are good for people with lower back problems.